# Python: dynamically add attributes to new-style class/obj

Tags: python, attributes, metaprogramming

Can I dynamically add attributes to instances of a new-style class (one that derives from `object`)?

Details:

I'm working with an instance of sqlite3.Connection.  Simply extending the class isn't an option because I don't get the instance by calling a constructor; I get it by calling `sqlite3.connect()`.

Building a wrapper doesn't save me much of the bulk for the code I'm writing.

Python 2.7.1

**Edit**

Right answers all.  But I still am not reaching my goal; instances of sqlite3.Connection bar my attempts to set attributes in the following ways (as do instances of `object` itself).  I always get an AttributeError:

```
> conn = sqlite3.connect([filepath])
> conn.a = 'foo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    conn.a = 'foo'
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'a'
> conn.__setattr__('a','foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    conn.__setattr__('a','foo')
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Help?

Comment: You can examine the actual __dict__ to find out what sqlite3 is using.  But that might be a C routine, in which case you'll be forced to wrap it somehow.

Comment: +1. Even `object.__setattr__(conn, 'a', 'foo')` raises AttributeError.  Interesting question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, unless the class is using [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots) or preventing attribute writing by overriding [`__setattr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__), or an internal Python class, or a Python class implemented natively (usually in C).

You can always try setting an attribute. Except for seriously weird `__setattr__` implementations, assigning an attribute to an instance of a class of one of the types mentioned above should raise an `AttributeError`.
In these cases, you'll have to use a wrapper, like this:

```
class AttrWrapper(object):
  def __init__(self, wrapped):
    self._wrapped = wrapped
  def __getattr__(self, n):
    return getattr(self._wrapped, n)
conn = AttrWrapper(sqlite3.connect(filepath))
```

Comment: I see now that you are correct, but it doesn't work for instances of sqlite3.Connection or `object` itself. (See edit above.)  Any help?

Comment: @JellicleCat Both fall under "internal Python class". I extended the answer with a wrapper. You mentioned using one in the question; but I'm not sure why it wouldn't solve the problem. If this wrapper does not work, please extend your question (or comment here) with a scenario in which it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Simple experimentation:

```
In []: class Tst(object): pass
   ..: 
In []: t= Tst()
In []: t.attr= 'is this valid?'
In []: t.attr
Out[]: 'is this valid?'
```

So, indeed it seems to be possible to do that.

**Update:**
But from the [documentation:](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) *SQLite is a C library that ...*, so it seems that you really need to wrap it.

Comment: I see now that you are correct, but it doesn't work for instances of sqlite3.Connection or `object` itself. (See edit above.)  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
    conn.a = 'foo',
```

or any dynamic assignment is valid, if conn is

```
    <type 'classobj'>.
```

Things like:

```
    c=object() 
    c.e=1
```

will raise an Attribute error. On the otherhand: Python allows you to do fantastic Metaclass programming:

```
    >>>from new import classobj
    >>>Foo2 = classobj('Foo2',(Foo,),{'bar':lambda self:'bar'})
    >>>Foo2().bar()
    >>>'bar'
    >>>Foo2().say_foo()
    >>>foo
```